# Check if user existed in cognito as federated user by using only email/username

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm having trouble implementing a feature where I need check if a user does not exist or is existing in cognito but as federated user. The prior is done without trouble but I'm stuck on the latter without any clue. I went through the cognito and amplify documents but couldn't find any clue. Could there be a work-around or a function that I don't know about, any suggest is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mutable custom user attribute on Cognito such as `isFederatedUser` and set this on user during user creation.

If this is not possible, you can call [list-users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/list-users.html) and filter the `identities` attribute.